# How can I change the volume increment from the volume buttons?

Tags: volume-control, buttons

On my Samsung Fascinate, the volume buttons change the volume by 3-4x the amount that I would like them to. Is it possible to adjust this amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation seems to be improved in the Android 2.2 update.

Answer (score 1):

You could try flashing a custom kernel with Voodoo Sound.  I don't know if it changes the volume increment but it may provide better values for those increments, and certainly a much better sound experience overall.

Comment: I'd like to avoid doing anything that will void my warranty.

Comment: That's valid.  The Galaxy S phones are super easy to revert to stock and nigh-impossible to brick though, so you can make it like it never happened ;)